# Is there a function to use in Python to pull an attachment from Smartsheets?

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am trying to pull information from the Smartsheets API- I can successfully get values of the cells and column headings. I am not using the SDK for the site, as it was not working properly.
There are attachments on some of the rows and I would like to download them and save them to my computer. 'attachments' looks like it should be a key value after I access the 'rows' key, but an error occurs saying that 'attachments' is not a key.
How do I access an attachment on a row without using the SDK?

```
for d in range(n_rows):
    print(data['rows'][d]['attachments']
```

Comment: What problem did you have with the Smartsheet Python SDK? I use it all the time and have never run into any issues. FWIW, using the SDK will save you a lot of time and effort compared to not doing so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is `data`?  What is `n_rows`?  You've given us almost zero details about this code.  We can't possibly help...

Comment: Junichiro Miyazaki- Thank you, that definitely helps some. 
/

Comment: Kim- I did try to use it, but for some reason when I downloaded all the files (at least I believe I did) from github, it kept telling me I did not have the all the modules. I went back to check and I am pretty sure I downloaded all the required files. I would love to use it instead of manually doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kim that  "using the SDK will save you a lot of time."

As for your question,  you may not have specified to include attachments.

```py
params = {
    'include': **'attachments'**
}

response = requests.get(f'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}}', params=params, headers=headers)
```

Or if you use SDK,

```py
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(
    sheet_id,
    include = **'attachments'**)
```

Or you could use the list attachments method.

```py
response=requests.get(f'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/attachments', headers=headers)
```

Either way, to download an attachment, you need to get an "attachmentId."

Then, with "attachmentId," use the get attachment method to  "Fetches a temporary URL that allows you to download an attachment. "

```py
response = requests.get(f'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/{sheetId}/attachments/{attachmentId}', headers=headers)
```

Or if you use SDK,

```py
attachment = smartsheet_client.Attachments.get_attachment(
  9283173393803140,  # sheet_id
  4583173393803140,  # attachment_id 
)
```